# Compile time guarantee a map has a key for each enum case

Tags: scala, scala-3

Given the following enum:

```
enum Connector:
  case CHAdeMO
  case Mennekes
  case CCS
  case Tesla
```

Is there a type like `Map[ConnectorType, Int]` but which would produce a compile error for:

```
Map(
  Connector.CHAdeMO -> 1,
  Connector.Mennekes -> 2,
  Connector.CCS -> 3,
)
```

That is the map does not contain a key for `Connector.Tesla`. In other words, in compile time the type should be akin to `((Connector.CHAdeMO, Int), (Connector.Mennekes, Int), (Connector.CCS, Int), (Connector.Tesla, Int))` but behave like a regular Map otherwise.

Comment: No. But you can write a structure that accepts a mapping with each key in which case the developer would get an arity mismatch with type hints. Or you can write compiler plug in but that's an overkill IMO

Comment: (thinking about it, you could probably leverage `HList` from `shapeless` to get something somewhat close to what you want

Comment: Scala 3 has `HList` built in, so I has expecting this to be kinda easy to implement.

Comment: Now that I think about it, this might be much easier with metaprogramming magic such as [`Mirror`](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/contextual/derivation.html#).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a solution using tuples ([Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/ze9RWmjqTSGwjHNWis9VTg)):

```scala
opaque type CheckedMap <: Map[Connector, Int] = Map[Connector, Int]

type Contains[E, T <: Tuple] <: Boolean = T match {
  case EmptyTuple => false
  case h *: t =>
    h match {
      case (E, _) => true
      case _      => Contains[E, t]
    }
}

type ContainsAll[S <: Tuple, T <: Tuple] = S match {
  case EmptyTuple => DummyImplicit
  case h *: t =>
    Contains[h, T] match {
      case true  => ContainsAll[t, T]
      case false => Nothing
    }
}

type AllConnectors = (
    Connector.CHAdeMO.type,
    Connector.Mennekes.type,
    Connector.CCS.type,
    Connector.Tesla.type
)

def checkedMap[T <: Tuple](t: T)(using
    @annotation.implicitNotFound(
      "Not all Connector types given."
    ) c: ContainsAll[AllConnectors, T]
): CheckedMap = t.toList.asInstanceOf[List[(Connector, Int)]].toMap
```

This will take a tuple of tuples `(Connector, Int)` and check if it contains all the types in another tuple of all `Connector` types. If the input contains all the connector types at least once, it looks for an implicit `DummyImplicit`, otherwise, it looks for an implicit `Nothing`, which it obviously doesn't find. The resulting error message is quite lengthy and unhelpful, so I put in a custom error message. Note that this doesn't check if there are duplicate keys, but could be trivially modified to do so.

Unfortunately, I found myself having to explicitly annotate the key-value pairs' types at the use site:

```scala
//Errors because Tesla is missing
checkedMap(
  (
    Connector.CHAdeMO -> 1: (Connector.CHAdeMO.type, Int),
    Connector.Mennekes -> 2: (Connector.Mennekes.type, Int),
    Connector.CCS -> 3: (Connector.CCS.type, Int)
  )
)
//Valid
checkedMap(
  (
    Connector.CHAdeMO -> 1: (Connector.CHAdeMO.type, Int),
    Connector.Mennekes -> 2: (Connector.Mennekes.type, Int),
    Connector.CCS -> 3: (Connector.CCS.type, Int),
    Connector.Tesla -> 4: (Connector.Tesla.type, Int)
  )
)
```